# How to use result of Suggester as query keyword for another /select search in Solr?

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I have solr suggest query like this `/suggest?q=smng&wt=xml` it gives me single result as

`<arr name="suggestion"><str>samsung</str></arr>`

Now I want to do a solr search using samsung as keyword.

Both task should be done on one single query that is rather than giving samsung as suggestion I want the search result using samsung. Same as result for `/select?q=samsung&wt=xml`. The samsung query in /select should be directly populated.
Is there any mechanism to do this?

Comment: you have to send two separate request , one for suggestion /suggest and other for querying /select. if you want to achieve both with one request then you should  write own request handler which handles this.

Comment: @vinod could you suggest any mechanism to write such request handler, I am new to solr and dont know how to implement two different requestHandler in custom single requestHandler.